# Get the discrete-time poles and zeros from continuous-time poles and zeros

Tags: frequency-response, transfer-function, poles-zeros, bilinear-transform

How do you implement the following function:

$$[Z^d, P^d, K^d] = \text{fcn} \,(Z^c, P^c, K^c),$$

where $Z^c = [z^c_m, ..., z^c_1]$, $P^c = [p^c_m, ..., p^c_1]$, and $K^c$ are zeros, poles, and gain of the continuous-time TF, and similarly $Z^d$, $P^d$, and $K^d$ are zeros, poles, and gain of the equivalent discrete-time TF with sampling time of $T_s$.

I have tried the following but it did not give me the correct answer:

$Z^d = e^{Z^c \times T_s}$

$P^d = e^{P^c \times T_s}$

$K^d = 1-e^{-K^c \times T_s}$    ---> (is the minus sign right?)

I am looking for some conversion formula that can handle all cases (including single/multiple poles or zeros).

**Note:** I do not want to use any Matlab built-in functions like c2d(), zp2tf(), or tf().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the continuous-time transfer function coefficients (or poles and zeros) from the corresponding discrete-time TF and vice versa?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53907/how-can-i-get-the-continuous-time-transfer-function-coefficients-or-poles-and-z)

Answer (score 1):

there are at least 3, likely more, methods.

1. $z = e^{sT}$
2. impulse invariant
3. bilinear transform

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on methods 1 and 3 or provide a reference for them.

Comment: 1st method : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_Z-transform_method

3rd method : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform